# Reductive subgroup corresponding to a subdiagram of the Dynkin diagram of a simple group

Tags: algebraic-groups

I am looking for a reference for the following well-known fact: For any subdiagram $\Delta_0$ of of the Dynkin diagram $\Delta=D(G)$
of an adjoint simple group $G$ over an algebraically closed field $k$, there exists a reductive subgroup of maximal rank $G_0\subset G$
with Dynkin diagram $\Delta_0$.

To be more precise, I am looking for a reference for a proof of the following well-known lemma:

Lemma 1.  Let $G$ be an adjoint, connected, simple algebraic group with Dynkin diagram $\Delta=D(G)$
over an algebraically closed field $k$ of any characteristic.
Let $\Delta_0$ be a  subdiagram of $\Delta$
(that is, a subset $\Pi_0$ of the set $\Pi$ of vertices of $\Delta$,
together with all the edges of $\Delta$ connecting pairs of vertices of $\Pi_0$).
Then there exists a connected reductive $k$-subgroup of maximal rank  $G_0$ of  $G$
such that the corresponding adjoint semisimple group $G_0^{ad}$
has  Dynkin diagram $\Delta_0$.

I know a simple proof of Lemma 1, but I would prefer to give a reference rather than a proof.

The proof goes as follows. Let $T$ be a maximal torus of $G$, and let $R=R(G,T)$ be the root system,
then our $\Pi$ is a basis of $R$.  Let $S$ be the subgroup of $T$ orthogonal to $\Pi_0$,
then it is a subtorus of $T$ (because $G$ is adjoint). 
Set $G_0=C_G(S)$, the centralizer of $S$ in $G$.
Then $G_0$ is a connected reductive subgroup of $G$.
It is easy to see that (the adjoint group of) $G_0$ has Dynkin diagram $\Delta_0$.

Note that Lemma 1 is a special case of the following Lemma 2,
for which I would also be happy to have a reference.

Lemma 2.   Let $G$ be an adjoint, connected, simple algebraic group 
over an algebraically closed field $k$ of any characteristic.
Let $T$ be a maximal torus of $G$, and let $R=R(G,T)$ be the root system.
Let $R_0$ be a closed symmetric subset of $R$.
Then there exists a connected reductive $k$-subgroup of maximal rank  $G_0$ of $G$
with root system $R_0$.

I will be grateful to any references, comments, etc. (also to a proof of Lemma 2).

Mikhail Borovoi

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Dear Mikhail,

If I understand correctly, your Lemma 2 is implied by
SGA 3 Exposé 22, Théorème 5.4.7.

Everything is on a general base S (that you may take as your algebraically closed field). The kind of subgroup you want is called "de type (R)" (see Définition 5.2.1) and a subset of R that corresponds to such a group is also called "de type (R)". Now the theorem above exactly says that when a subset of R is closed, it is "de type (R)" which exactly means that there is a corresponding connected subgroup of G. By the way, Théorème 5.4.7 does not assume the subset to be symmetric, and you get things like Borel subgroups if you take only "half" of the roots. In the symmetric case, the group is reductive by Proposition 5.10.1.

Hope this helps.

Baptiste Calmès

Comment: This theorem from SGA 3 is an efficient reference for Lemma 2, though
the background and setting are more than needed to describe the
structure theory over an algebraically closed field.   Concretely,
the desired subgroup is generated by a maximal torus together with
pairs of root subgroups (or the rank 1 semisimple groups they generate).   The standard commutation relations show that no further
roots appear if the given set of roots is closed and symmetric.    Here
as in SGA 3, the Lie algebra reflects accurately what is going on
since the subgroup is of maximal rank.  

Answer (score 5):

Here is a short answer, which can be filled in further.  Whether your group
is of adjoint type or not probably makes little difference.   Work going back
to a fundamental paper of Borel and deSiebenthal leads to explicit information
about the subgroups of maximal rank in a connected reductive group (eventually
over any algebraically closed field, though at first just in characteristic 0).

For your Lemma 1, you just need a Levi subgroup of a parabolic subgroup, as
described in any of the standard texts on linear algebraic groups (Borel,
Springer, or my book).   For Lemma 2, the foundations were laid over fairly
general fields by Borel and Tits in their 1965 paper Groupes reductifs in
the IHES Publ. Math.    (I'll have to dig out more explicit references.)
Anyway, an overview with references about subgroups of maximal rank is given
in section 2.1 of my 1995 AMS book, Conjugacy Classes in Semisimple Algebraic
Groups (algebraically closed case).

Concerning terminology, you are really working with subsets of the root
system in each case (with the Dynkin diagram just a way of encoding data
about the chosen simple roots).    Bourbaki's Chapter VI has a lot of
root system discussion related to Borel-Tits, for example involving
symmetric subsets.

Comment: Your proof of Lemma 1 is clear. Concerning Lemma 2, I would be grateful for details.

Comment: I will look further at literature later this weekend, but meanwhile
I think the essential point coming from the 1949 Borel-de Siebenthal
paper (as generalized to the algebraic group situation in any characteristic) is that the connected reductive subgroups of maximal
rank are generated by a maximal torus along with root subgroups
belonging to a root system found via the *extended* Dynkin diagram.
Sets of simple roots only generate the root systems in Levi
subgroups; the others are usually called "pseudo-Levi", like the
copy of `$A_2$` inside `$G_2$`. 

Comment: Evgeny Vdovin  in his notes in Russian http://math.nsc.ru/~vdovin/alggroups.pdf gives the following algorithm. From the Dynkin diagram of a root system R we construct the extended Dynkin diagram, and then from this extended Dynkin diagram we remove one or more vertices. Then for each of the remaining connected components we can repeat this procedure. The diagrams that we can obtain in this way are the Dynkin diagrams of all symmetric closed subsets of R. Vdovin refers to  Borel-de Siebenthal and to Dynkin, Mat. Sbornik 1952.

Comment: Yes, this is the way it was understood originally.   Even though the
papers assume characteristic 0, the ideas carry over well to any
algebraically closed field.  But in later literature more
emphasis was placed on describing centralizers of semisimple elements as in Chapter 2 of my 1995 book and the sources cited.
This constructs subgroups of maximal rank less directly than you
want. It's hard to locate a reference for your Lemma 2 short of
SGA 3.   (But see Bourbaki, VI.1.7 on closed symmetric sets of
roots, especially Prop. 23.)


